# Java -how to get variable form JTeXtField and use in algorithm J48

Tags: java, swing, static, compiler-errors

I would like to create a small application in Java- one button and one JTextField.Additionally I use code which generate a 'tree' from  J48 algorithm (I find code in the web when I looking for WEKA totorial).Variable form text field should be use in this code ( implementation J48). I create something like this, but it dont work :

```
package visio;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;



import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.gui.treevisualizer.PlaceNode2;
import weka.gui.treevisualizer.TreeVisualizer;

public class Visio extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    int temp;
    JTextField pole;
    JButton button = new JButton("bb");

    public Visio() {

        setSize(400, 400);
        setTitle("okno");

        setLayout(null);


        button.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 20);
        add(button);

        button.addActionListener(this);

        pole = new JTextField("");
        pole.setBounds(20, 70, 150, 20);
        add(pole);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Visio okienko = new Visio();
        okienko.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        okienko.setVisible(true);

        // train classifier
        J48 cls = new J48();

        BufferedReader reader;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:/Desktop/weka.arff"));
        Instances data = new Instances(reader);
        reader.close();




        /* Instances data = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0])));*/
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - temp);
        cls.buildClassifier(data);

        // display classifier
        final javax.swing.JFrame jf =
                new javax.swing.JFrame("Weka Classifier Tree Visualizer: J48");
        jf.setSize(500, 400);
        jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        TreeVisualizer tv = new TreeVisualizer(null,
                cls.graph(),
                new PlaceNode2());
        jf.getContentPane().add(tv, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jf.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                jf.dispose();
            }
        });

        jf.setVisible(true);
        tv.fitToScreen();


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        temp = Integer.parseInt(pole.getText());


    }
}
```

Help me.I have an error : non static variable cannot be referenced from static context

Comment: You need to get most of that code out of your static main method and instead use objects and instance variables and non-static methods to solve your problem. Consider going through some introductory tutorials in Java and object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 1):

It means you are using "temp", a variable that is not static in your static main method .

```
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - temp); // you use it here
```

If you want to fix it all you would have to do is change your variable declaration of "temp":

```
static int temp;
```

But make sure you [learn what static means](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), no point in being able to write code you do not understand ;), also remember that it is best to avoid static variables if convenient.

The other option would be to move the code in your main method into the constructor of "Visio". Since the constructor for "Visio" is not static, you can access all the instance variables without getting errors.

It would be as easy as copy-pasting the code from "main" into "Visio", just make sure you change "okienko.(whatever)" to "this.(whatever)". (While you don't have to put in the "this" keyword, I like to do it anyway when referring to inherited members; it makes the source code more clear).

Comment: Please don't recommend that he use static variables which would break OOP compliance and when instance variables would work just fine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels In his case making one variable static is much easier than making the rest of his code "non-static".

Comment: It's easier but it's wrong and would do nothing but reinforce a bad habit.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm here to answer his question, not to teach him programming practices. Anyway, I added a solution to keep his variables instance ones.

Comment: @jesusplsplus *"I'm here to answer his question, not to teach him programming practices"* I would argue that they mutually inclusive goals. You shouldn't try one without other -IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer Whatever just forget it, I added another way it could be done without statics.